# iText filling XFA form with Extended Features

Tags: itext

I want to use iText to update a LiveCycle PDF with Extended Features enabled to:

1. Fill in the XFA form fields
2. Make the fields read-only
3. Preserve the Extended Features setting

I have figured out #1 and #3, but everything I've tried for #2 breaks the PDF in some way.

- Disabling the "fill form" permission using an owner password makes the XFA fields invisible
- Modifying the  elements in the template to add "access='readOnly'" causes a "document has been changed since it was created and use of extended features is no longer available" error and the XFA fields become invisible
- Using XfaForm.fillXfaForm(node, true) causes the same problem as above

Comment: items 2 and 3 might contradict each other: To preserve Extended Features you normally are not allowed to make changes other than those required to fill the form at hand. Changing the properties of the form, e.g. by making fields read-only, is not allowed. If you want to make all fields read-only, though, you might want to try removing the usage righta signature (which is the mechanism with which the Extended Features are provided).

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. Working some other angles...

Comment: Can you explain how you achieved items 1 and 3. We have the problem that we loose the extended features.